# Installing OpenMediaVault without keyboard and monitor

Tags: debian, system-installation, usb-drive, headless, preseed

So I got the parts to my server delivered and assembled it.
Now I have the problem that I don't have access to a monitor or keyboard and would like to install OMV to my server. I plan on running the OS from an USB stick (I know this is not recommended, but I got a SLC based stick, so it should be fine).

I have a MacBook that's running OS X, could I setup the USB here and move it to the server and then just boot it there?

Otherwise I guess I could use some sort of preseed file for headless installation, but I'm not well-versed in unix enviroments so I'm not sure how I should set it up. From what I gather I need to get the install iso on an USB and use that to install to another USB, is this possible to set up with a preseed file?

I think OMV locks the OS drive, so ideally the stick should be split (1GB OS – 7GB Storage) so that the one half can be used for storing plugins and other stuff.

On a sidenote, found this while looking for help/guides:
https://gist.github.com/ngnpope/3806732

Can I benefit from this in some way?